# PHP PDO: select из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Предыстория**

Вроде похожих вопросов на форуме предостаточно, но мне они почему-то не помогли.

Я хочу сделать список 50-ти свежих (не раньше, чем месяц назад) ответов (новые подписчики, лайки, комментарии) для социальной, да простит меня Цукерберг, сети.

То есть, нужно объединить 3 таблицы, чтоб одновременно выбрать из них максимум 50 строк и отсортировать эти строки по датеВремени. Вот всё, на что оказался способен мой мозг:

```
$getReplies=$pdo->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM followers    
            FULL OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.replyToUserId = :id AND comments.dateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
            FULL OUTER JOIN likes ON likes.toId = :id AND likes.dateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
            WHERE followers.toId = :id AND followers.dateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
            ORDER BY followers.dateTime DESC, comments.dateTime DESC, likes.dateTime DESC 
            LIMIT 50"
        );
        $getReplies->execute(array('id' => $out[0]));
        $replies=$getReplies->fetchAll();
```

Но на выходе ничего не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста, я уже весь бубен отплясал.

**▼ НА ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ ПРОБЛЕМА ТАКАЯ ▼**

По нижесказанному совету делал с помощью UNION. Но я по-прежнему получаю пустой массив, даже для самых простых запросов, которые без проблем работают по одиночке. Вот что здесь может быть не так?

```
$getReplies=$pdo->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM followers WHERE toId = '1'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM likes WHERE toId = '1'
        ");
        $getReplies->execute();
        $replies=$getReplies->fetchAll();
```

Comment: join обычно соединяются таблицы, которые как то логически связаны друг с другом. Таким образом что бы в одной строке была представлена информация из нескольких таблиц. кроме того, конкретно `FULL OUTER JOIN` в MySQL нет в принципе. Что то мне подсказывает, что вам нужен `UNION`

Comment: @Mike , походу, вы правы. Но я по-прежнему получаю пустой массив. Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: _Всегда_ проверяйте запросы на ошибки и выводите эти ошибки куда нибудь. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.error-handling.php  А вообще запросы перед тем как совать в php код надо отладить в каком нибудь MySQL workbench или phpmyadmin или еще в каком нибудь средстве. Оно бы вам сразу сказало что у вас количество полей в подзапросах не совпадает (я сильно сомневаюсь, что у вас эти 2 таблицы имеют абсолютно одинаковую структуру). union требует что бы запросы возвращали одинаковое количество колонок с одинаковыми типами данных. И вообще использование `*` плохой тон, всегда указывайте нужные колонки

Comment: @Mike , каюсь. Один клятый столбец в одной из таблиц попортил всё веселье. Но то уже мои проблемы. Вам спасибо, можете записать последний коммент в ответ, галку поставлю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю выглядеть запрос должен как то так:

```
select * from (
 select dateTime, a, b, c
   from followers
  where toId = :id AND dateTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  order by dateTime desc
  limit 50
) A
UNION ALL
select * from (
 select dateTime, a, b, c
   from likes
  where toId = :id AND dateTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  order by dateTime desc
  limit 50
) A
  order by dateTime desc
  limit 50
```

- Если не стоит задачи отсеить дубли лучше использовать `UNION ALL`, он быстрее (а вряд ли могут быть дубли в информации из разных таблиц).
- Данные надо максимально сократить заранее, в каждой из частей запроса, что бы `union` не выполнять лишнюю работу объединяя то, что будет выброшено потом.
- Количество колонок и типы данных, возвращаемые каждым подзапросом должны быть одинаковы